# Firefox browser authentication using Webdriver-Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am trying to handle browser authentication while automating using Selenium-WebDriver in Java.

I don't want to use:
"http://username:password@site.com/page"

This fails to resolve the problem when the password itself contains "@".

Neither do I want to create a separate firefox profile with saved credentials and auto authenticate addons.

Apologies if questions appears to be repeated but an accurate solutions was not available.

Comment: Do you try with escape charater for the @ symbol. I don't know if this will work, but I am curious.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov: No it doesn't work with escape character.